# Filter by typing in textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I'm using the code below in order to bind my `datagridview` and the `select` statement in order to get the records I need.

Everything works fine in these lines of code, but I would like to automatically filter the records when the user types something into `textbox` and when deletes the data, the records return to the initial state, when the form is loading. Could anyone give me some tips?

Here is my code:

```
public nir()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    nir_load();
}

void nir_load()
{
    string cs = "Data Source=IS020114\\CODRINMA;Initial Catalog=gcOnesti;Integrated Security=True";
    string select = "select p.cod as Numar, p.data as Data, p.doc_cod as NrDocFurnizor, g.nume as Gestiune, c.nume as Furnizor, p.validat as Validat, p.facturat as Contat from primar p inner join gestiuni g on p.part2=g.gest_id inner join cf c on p.part1=c.cf_id where p.tip=2";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select, con);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
}

private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = "Data Source=IS020114\\CODRINMA;Initial Catalog=gcOnesti;Integrated Security=True";
    string select = "select p.cod as Numar, p.data as Data, p.doc_cod as NrDocFurnizor, g.nume as Gestiune, c.nume as Furnizor, p.validat as Validat, p.facturat as Contat from primar p inner join gestiuni g on p.part2=g.gest_id inner join cf c on p.part1=c.cf_id where cod='" +txtnr.Text+"' and data='" + dtpData.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +"' and p.tip=2";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select, con);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
}
```

Comment: In same situation I have used jQuery. On my page there was an input field and below it div-table that loads data from SQL Server. When user type something in input field, the table below is filtered based on user inputs.

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to search, as the title implies or filter as your descrition does. Both are answered here quite often..

Comment: @TaW - to filter, I explained myself wrong. But I was able to do that using `KeyUp` event.

Answer (score 0):

I used `private void txtNumber_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)` event and it worked fine.